# tabulator link that has a value of false

Tags: tabulator

In tabulator 3.x I had a column of links where the display value was either true / false. Url was different (hidden) value in the table. I updated to 4.x and the true links show up, the false ones do not.
http://tabulator.info/

I'd like to restore the original behaviour if possible since the link makes it clear that there is somewhere to go.

Otherwise I could change it to a tickCross, but I'd still want it to be a link.

Anyone have any examples of how to get this to work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have not heard, but I figure it's a bug so I've opened a ticket.
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2500

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would consider it surprising that the values show up at all considering neither is a valid string, which is what a label should be and they are both Boolean's.

In this case i would suggest that you use a [Mutator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/mutators) to map your Boolean into a string which would be a valid label.